# How can i do a for loop with seconds/milliseconds using pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a snake game, and am having a little trouble getting the snake to move correctly. When i run this code he does go across the screen. but i cant get the display to update every {}'s .

I was wondering if there was a way to set up a for loop like this:

```
for seconds in { idk}:
    pygame.display.update()
    self.x += self.speed

import pygame
import time
pygame.init()

## creates window
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
## gives titale to window
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake attempt")

class Character():
    def __init__(self, height= 40, width = 40,x = 50,y= 50,speed = 20):
            self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = 20
    def create(self):
    ## rect(draw on, ( colors) (pos.x , pos.y . width, height))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0, 0) , (self.x, self.y, 
self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.update()
    def movement(self):
        self.x += self.speed
        pygame.display.update()


game_on = True
game_off = False

player = Character()

while game_on:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

## gives all events that happen while Game_on = True

        for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

## call on sys.exit()Caracter class         
    player.create()
    player.movement()
```

Basically i just want the player to move across the screen by so many spaces every how ever many seconds. while having the display refresh every time

Comment: you can't use `for` loop in `while` loop because it will stop other elements. You have to use current `while` to do it . You can use `current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get current time and set at start `time_to_change_speed = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000` and later check `if current_time >= time_to_change_speed: self.x += self.speed ; time_to_change_speed = current_time + 3000`

Comment: you should use `update()` only once in every loop - don't use it after every blit/draw but after all blits/draws. If you use `update()` after every blit then it can display incomplete image.

Comment: you could use `pygame.time.Clock()` to control game's speed in FPS (Frames Per Second) and then in every frame you can move by 20/FPS pixels, and you get 20 pixels in 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a perfectly nice event loop with 100ms delay.
Don't create any additional delay loops.

This runs ten times per second:

```
    player.movement()
```

Whatever speed or behavior you want to produce,
should happen within that method.
You will see the behavior evolving over time due to
the method being repeatedly called, ten times a second.

And as furas helpfully points out, there's no need for `.update()`
within the create method, better to defer it until movement is complete.

Note that what's visible on-screen for 100ms is the *previous* position,
before advancing `x`.